# Как вывести (перемотать) неподгруженный текст в терминале psql?

Tags: postgresql, консоль

При запросе хелпера, как в примере, или при выборке из большой таблицы, выводится только часть текста, которая внизу ограничивается строкой "-- Далее --", можно ли каким-то хоткеем вывести весь текст, чтоб не держать зажатым Enter?[image: пример с \h DROP]

Comment: Хоткей для прерывания вывода тоже поможет.

Answer (score 0):

клавиша R (то есть 'rest') проматывает весь текст до конца